# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFY BY 4545'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I need some help because I can't figure out why I got this mistake with mysql and python.
Here's a bit of my program:

```
        mkuser = utilisateur
        mkpass = password
        creation = "CREATE USER '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFY BY %s" % (mkuser, mkpass)
        cursor.execute(creation)

        granting = "GRANT ALL ON *.*TO '%s'@ 'localhost'" % (mkuser)
        cursor.execute(granting)
```

utilisateur is a variable that the user should type, the same for password, with numbers. And when I try I got this mistake --> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFY BY 4545'
If someone could explain me what's my mistake I'd be really greatful ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a spelling error:

Following should work:

```
creation = "CREATE USER '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY %s" % (mkuser, mkpass)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I can't believe I didn't see it before... I turned in circle for one hour with it... I'm so sorry for the "trouble" (I'm not sure for trouble I mean: Je suis désolé pour le dérangement...)

Comment: @Chris B Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes

Comment: Yep, I agree, Thanks a lot again !!

Answer (score 0):

Also quote your password:

```
creation = "CREATE USER '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'" % (mkuser, mkpass)
```